Issue with WooCommerce Coupon Expiration Dates Changing During CSV Import
I’m encountering an issue with coupon expiration dates when working with the bulk coupon generator and the CSV import/export functionality in WooCommerce. Here's the full context:
What I Did:
Generated bulk coupons using the WooCommerce coupon generator.
Set the expiration date to 31st December 2025 at midnight.
Exported the coupons to a CSV file to make a prefix correction.
Re-imported the corrected CSV back into WooCommerce.
The Issue:
After re-importing the coupons, the expiration dates were unexpectedly changed to 30th December 2025 instead of the intended 31st December 2025.
What I Tried:
Updated the expiration dates directly in the MySQL database using the following queries:
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
SET pm.meta_value = '2025-12-31'
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
AND pm.meta_key = 'expiry_date';

UPDATE wp_postmeta pm
SET pm.meta_value = '1767185999'
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'date_expires';

While these updates reflect correctly in the database, the expiration dates in the WooCommerce dashboard still show as 30th December 2025.
Environment Details:
WooCommerce version: 3.3.6
WordPress version: 5.6.40
Database: MySQL
i have a lot of coupons in my website and direct db manipulation is the only way i can make those bulk changes efficiently.

It may depend on timezone settings and how this coupon module / woocommerce interprets dates and times stored in the postmeta table. For example, 1767185999 represents Dec 31 2025 12:59:59 (almost 1pm) in UTC/GMT. Not the midnight you indicated in your question. This value to represent midnight, you (well, your server) need to be in GMT+11 timezone. I would create a single new coupon with the correct expiration date and check its expiration values in the database. If those are the same, then you are not facing a mysql issue, but some kind of a woocommerce config issue.

@Shadow i am not that well versed in it, so basically i need to do a GMT +11 not UTC? fyi the server is hosted in US hosting location, and i tried setting 1767185999 as a way to kick up the date at its hard stuck on a day before on 30th. i will try your suggestion.

I would not change timezone settings. I merely pointed out the impact of timezones have on interpreting time values. I would encourage you to create a new coupon and see how it is configured to report the correct expiration date and time!

First, there is a missing code line at the beginning of your provided code.
Then "expiry_date" meta_key doesn't exist by default for WooCommerce coupons in the database.
The correct meta_key is only "date_expires", where it's a timestamp based on date (there is no time handled for this timestamp, only the date value in seconds).
Server timezone:
As your server time zone seems to be in the USA, you may need to subtract between 5 and 8 hours in seconds to the timestamp value in my code below, depending on the server time zone. 
The timestamp value "1767139200" is for the 31 December 2025 in GMT/UTC.
So you need a unique query like:
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = '1767139200'
WHERE `meta_key` = 'date_expires'
  AND `post_id` IN
    (SELECT `ID`
     FROM `wp_posts`
     WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_coupon');

It should work.

This solution worked but i have around 80k coupons in this site and only 55k were updated, rest still stuck
